# How to get row and column value in a grid layout?

Tags: android, grid-layout

I have defined a GridView in Android Studio, and I want to get the row and column value of each cell. Basically I am building a Tic Tac Toe kind of app and I want the value of each cell so that I can find if that cell is empty or filled.

```
int chance = 0;
int[] pos = new int[9];
public void click(View view) {
    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
    if(chance == 0) {
           counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
           chance = 1;
           // Here I want to update the that this particular cell is 
           clicked and it should be updated in pos array.
    }
    else {
           counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
           chance = 0;
           // Similarly here also it should be updated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tags for each component in grid layout in the layout xml file, like :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="0" />
```

Then use     `.getTag()`    function to get the component

```
counter.getTag().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onItemClickListener` on your `GridView` and perform your task in `onItemClick` method.

For example, add this in your Activity class:

```
yourGridViewObject.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    if(chance==0)
    {
        counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
           chance = 1;
         pos[position]=*updated value*;
    }
    else
    {
         counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
           chance = 0;
           pos[position]=*updated value*;
    }
    your_adapter_object.notifyDataSetChanged();

  }
});
```

Hope this helps.